# Freeze Linux when log is full

Tags: rhel, security, logs, audit

Is it possible to configure a Linux server to stop all operations when it cannot create logs, similar to the security policy in Windows called *"Audit: Shut down system immediately if unable to log security audits"*?

To goal would be to prevent a server from doing anything if it cannot log what it is doing. To prevent an attacker from filling the disk, or otherwise preventing the log from being written, and then carry on malicious operations from that server.

Comment: By stop all operations, what exactly you mean ?

Comment: How about checking if you are able to write to a file and "stop" the operations if you are not able to do so ?

Creating a log file and checking the data using `FILE=<your log file > if [ -w "$FILE" ] 
then
   echo "Able to write to the logfile, continuing operations"
else
   echo "Not able to log to the logfile"
fi`

Comment: Something similar to https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/security-policy-settings/audit-shut-down-system-immediately-if-unable-to-log-security-audits. You cannot login, no service is responding. All you can do is logon as admin and archive+clear the logs.

Comment: I am looking for something robust, that would be difficult for the attacker to circumvent/disable.